# How do I apply floatHead to a dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the plugin floatHead to keep my thead on a fixed position.
This works for tables that are existing in the DOM upon loading the plugin.
I need it however to work on dynamically created tables as well.

`$('#tbl').floatThead();`
Trying to apply the plugin on newly created tables results in an error:
 `TypeError: $(...).floatThead is not a function`

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anonymousdummy/zerg1w5o/)

Comment: Add more code or make fiddle

Comment: Have you tried `.floatThead('reflow')`

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour I did but getting the same error `$('#tbl').floatThead('reflow');`

Comment: Try referencing jQuery.min.js before floatThead plugin

Comment: @Master Yoda, reordering the plugin made the error dissapear, but still didn't give me the desired result (floating header) see https://jsfiddle.net/anonymousdummy/zerg1w5o/

Answer (score 0):

Know nothing about "floatThead", and i am not Jquery expert, but you can attach event handler to dynamic element like this:

```
$(document).on('load', '#tbl', function(e) {
    $(this).floatThead();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the class for all dynamic tables as **.tbl**

```
$(document).on('load', '.tbl', function(e) {
    $(this).floatThead();
});
```